# How do I convert a System::String^ to const char*?

Tags: c++-cli, char

I'm developing an app in C++/CLI and have a csv file writing library in unmanaged code that I want to use from the managed portion. So my function looks something like this:

```
bool CSVWriter::Write(const char* stringToWrite);
```

...but I'm really struggling to convert my shiny System::String^ into something compatible. Basically I was hoping to call by doing something like:

```
if( m_myWriter->Write(String::Format("{0}",someValueIWantToSave)) )
{
    // report success
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert System::String to const char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335426/how-to-convert-systemstring-to-const-char)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
const char* str = (const char*) (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString)).ToPointer();
```

From [Dev Shed](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/convert-system-string-to-const-char-116569.html).

Comment: Missing Marshal::FreeHGlobal(...); which can result in memory leak.

Answer (score 11):

As [mcandre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098431/how-do-i-convert-a-systemstring-to-const-char/1098475#1098475) mentions, [Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) is correct.  But don't forget to free the newly allocated resource with [Marshal::FreeHGlobal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx), when the string is no longer in use.

Alternatively, you can use the [msclr::interop::marshal_as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx) template to create the string resource and automatically release it when the call exits the resource's scope.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of what types need which conversion in the [overview of marshalling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).