# C++/CLI Converting System::String to const char*

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, system

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2008
I want to join some strings, and then use it with "system" command.

I tried to do it like this:

```
System::String^ link;
link = "wget.exe --output-document=log http://ADDRESS";
link = link + System::String::Copy(textBox_login->Text);
link = link + "&passwd=";
link = link + System::String::Copy(textBox_passwd->Text);
system(link); //LINE WITH ERROR
```

But i get  error C2664: 'system' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const char *'

I appreciate any help ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert System::String to const char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335426/how-to-convert-systemstring-to-const-char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098431/how-do-i-convert-a-systemstring-to-const-char).

In essence, the problem is that the [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) function expects a variable of the type `const char*` rather than `System::String`.

So you need to convert the string to a const char* (Using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-between-char-and-systemstring-in-c-cli/56779#56779)) and use that as an argument for the system function.

```
IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(clistr);
const char* linkStr = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
system(linkStr);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);
```

Comment: everything works fine, but when it gets to: link = link + "&passwd=" it cuts everything that is afterwords in string

Comment: you forgot to call `Marshal::FreeHGlobal`, this leaks memory.

Comment: This is not exception-safe.  Use RAII.  Microsoft already built a nice RAII object for you too, the `marshal_context`.

Answer (score 2):

To use system as you do, you will need Marshalling. This requires extra precautions which can lead to unforeseen pain.

I recommend that you call wget via the [System::Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(VS.71).aspx)

It integrates with .NET much better and you can use System::String^ directly

Answer (score 0):

after doing as Yacoby said, almost everything works fine, but when it gets to

```
link = link + "&passwd=";
```

it cuts everything what is afterwords in string.
when i remove '&' it works just fine... i need the '&' sign

Answer (score 0):

You got the technical solution to your problem but here are a couple other things you might want to consider:

- Instead of opening a process to do the HTTP request for you, use an API (.NET or C++, in .NET it's much easier than standard C++, look at [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)) to do this. Especially if you plan to do something with the response.
- In general if you're appending to a `String` multiple times, prefer a `StringBuilder`. Since `String` is immutable in .NET, every append requires a new `String` to be constructed.
- In this case, **don't** use a `String` to build the URL in the first place. Use [System::Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) instead.