# how to convert System::String to const char*?

Tags: c++-cli

how to convert 'String^' to 'const char*'?

```
     String^ cr = ("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + this->txtSSID->Text + " key=" + this->txtPASS->Text);
system(cr);
```

Error :

```
1   IntelliSense: argument of type "System::String ^" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
```

Comment: Copy/paste the title of your question into the Google search box.  Lots and lots of hits.

Comment: Ok, this one has the good answer, using it as dupe target for many others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using the [`msclr::interop::marshal_context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384854.aspx) class:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
```

Then:

```
String^ something = "something";

msclr::interop::marshal_context ctx;
const char* converted = ctx.marshal_as<const char*>(something);

system(converted);
```

The buffer for `converted` will be freed when `ctx` goes out of scope.

But in your case it would be much easier to just call an equivalent managed API:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("netsh", "the args");
```

Answer (score 1):

The 4 methods on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311259/how-to-convert-from-system-string-to-char-in-visual-c
didn't work for me in VS2015. I followed this advice instead :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx
and just put it into a function for convenience.
I deviated from the suggested solution where it allocates new memory
for the char* - I prefer to leave that to the caller, even though this
poses an extra risk.

```
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;

void Str2CharPtr(String ^str, char* chrPtr)
{
   // Pin memory so GC can't move it while native function is called
   pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wchPtr = PtrToStringChars(str);

   // Convert wchar_t* to char*
   size_t  convertedChars = 0;
   size_t  sizeInBytes = ((str->Length + 1) * 2);

   wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, chrPtr, sizeInBytes, wchPtr, sizeInBytes);
}
```