# A value of type "System::String ^" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "jstring"

Tags: string, java-native-interface, c++-cli

So as the title says this the error I get while running this code, which is written in C++/CLI:

```
String^ somethig(const char* string)
{
  // Some code

}
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Class_nativeClass
 (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj,jstring string)
{
jboolean isCopyString;
const char *c_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, &isCopyString);
jstring example = somethig(c_string);
return example;
}
```

I get the error on line:

```
jstring example = something(c_string);
```

Specifically at ***example***. Now I know what the error means, I just don't know how to get jstring to accept the function ***something***. Is there a conversion method that works with functions to make it an acceptable type for jstring?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The method `env->NewString()` will take a Unicode buffer and return a jstring. You'll need to convert from `String^` to `wchar_t*`, and then pass that to `env->NewString()`. (Or `env->NewStringUTF()` to convert a UTF8-encoded `char*`, which will work for any ASCII `char*` as well.)

However, if you need to create a jstring, then can you modify `somethig` to return the jstring directly, or modify the input `char*`? Without seeing how `somethig` is implemented, taking a trip through `String^` seems unnecessary.

### Edit

Here's the conversion code you would use. Again, if you can modify `something`, there are better solutions than this.

You need to convert the `String^` to a `wchar_t` using [`StringToHGlobalUni`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), then you can convert that to a `jstring` using [`NewString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4925). Don't forget, you *must* free the `wchar_t*` using [`FreeHGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

```
String^ managedString = something(...);
wchar_t* unmanagedWideString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(managedString).ToPointer();
jstring example = env->NewString(unmanagedWideString, managedString->Length);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(unmanagedWideString);
return example;
```

Disclaimer: I'm not a JNI expert, and I didn't check my syntax in a compiler.

Comment: Does `env->NewString()` work with functions as well? If so can you please write an example using my example as to how I do the conversion? The problem is that `something` is calling a method from a dll file and that method only can be referenced as a `String^`. Again please show me the code to the conversion. Thank you.

Comment: See edit. You need to convert from `String^` to `wchar_t*` first, then use `NewString` to convert to `jstring`.

Comment: You can use `marshal_context` for this conversion instead of `StringToHGlobalUni`. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29336318/3764814). Or you could use `PtrToStringChars` and avoid the copy altogether.

Comment: There are many ways to convert from `String^` to `wchar_t*`, which are answered in many questions on StackOverflow. (The variety is why I answered the question without specific code originally.)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I got the error "a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "wchar_t *" at `Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni` I don't know where its reading void to be honest.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the help. For some reason, VS is not recoginizing the header. For some reason I get: "error C2653: 'msclr' : is not a class or namespace name." Even after puting `using namespace msclr::interop`

Comment: @Saleh see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) - you need to `#include <msclr/marshal.h>` - is that what you tried?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes at the very to as well.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski does `#include <msclr/marshal.h>` work with C++/CLI? Cause I get this error:  1 IntelliSense: "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous  1 IntelliSense: "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\servprov.h

Comment: @Saleh yes, `#include <msclr/marshal.h>` is for C++/CLI. Your error relates to a different header file.