# Transferring a file path from Windows form to function

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, path, c++-cli, filenames

I'm quite a novice when it comes to user interface development in C ++. Until now I have always started in the Command Window my program.
To start a program I've used the following call.
`Prg.exe -slicesize 3 -infill 5 -model cube.stl -ascii -eulerangles 0 0 0`

This was processed using the following code

```
for (int i = 1; i <argc;) {
    if (0 == strcmp (argv [i], "-slicesize")) {
        slice size = atof (argv [i + 1]);
        i + = 2;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp (argv [i], "-infill")) {
        infill = atof (argv [i + 1]);
        i + = 2;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp (argv [i], "-model")) {
        strcpy (model file name, argv [i + 1]);
        i + = 2;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp (argv [i], "-ascii")) {
        isBinaryFormat = false;
        i + = 1;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp (argv [i], "-eulerangles")) {
        eulerAngles.x = atof (argv [i + 1]);
        eulerAngles.y = atof (argv [i + 2]);
        eulerAngles.z = atof (argv [i + 3]);
        i + = 4;
    }
    else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

The given file, a .stl file, was than processed to a triangle mesh.

```
TriangleMesh mesh;
if (stlToMeshInMemory(modelFileName, &mesh, isBinaryFormat)!=0)
    return 1;
```

Here, the selected file but must be in the same folder as the program. But the finished program must be dynamic.

Now I have to develop a user interface. For that I have created in my project a button that opens a OpenFileDialog. The path to the selected file is displayed here in a text box.

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
        openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "stl files (*.stl)|*.stl|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

        if( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            textBox1->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName;
        }
}
```

With this code I can search for files and let me see the path. But how can I pass the file name to the function `stlToMeshInMemory`?

Another question would be to what file I need to program my functions. I use Visual Studio 2012 and have in my project currently three files. Until now I have found the following. In myForm.h [Design] I can make the surface. In myForm.h I program, what should happen when a control element is actuated. In MyForm.cpp I so far only

```
#include "myForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System :: Windows :: Forms;

[STAThread]
void main (array <String ^> ^ arg) {
Application :: EnableVisualStyles ();
Application :: SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault (false);

Project2 :: MyForm form;
Application :: Run (% form);
}
```

Do I have to write the entire program that I've developed in MyForm.cpp? The aim is to read a file and when a button "Translate" is operated to output a file.

Comment: That's not `c++`, that's `c++-cli`. Please update your question with relevant tags.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that. I edited the tags

Comment: Hard to see the hangup.  You originally used a variable named *modelFileName*.  Now you have to use a different variable, like *textBox->Text*.  You probably need a type conversion to go from a String^ to an std::string or a const char*.  Lots and lots of existing Q+A about that.  The MSDN page [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I pretty new to this, so I have some problems to understand your comment. I know I can convert the text in the textbox form string to a char. But I do not know what to do with this char. I normally just use a console apllication, so I never before developed a UI. Is it possible to just parse the char to the function?

Comment: See [how to convert System::String to const char*?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29336318/3764814) for an example os using `marshal_context` (which is what you'll need to convert from a `System::String^` to `const char*`