# Can't convert System::String ^' to 'LPCSTR' in serial programming

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, serial-port, c++-cli

I am newbie in C++, I design a window form application for serial programming, for this, I choose a comboBox for choosing 'COM PORT' and a button to initialize serial communication. In button programming a tried to copy the text of Combobox in a string type variable 'tab' and use it as COM PORT selection.But when I compile the code , I got this error:-

> error C2664: 'CreateFileA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'System::String ^' to 'LPCSTR'

So, of-course I have to convert my tab from string type to LPCSTR type, but the problem is I have no idea what is LPCSTR, so please help me to convert string into LPCSTR type.
Here in my code for initialization Button.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                System::String^ tab;
                 tab=this-> comboBox1->Text ;
                 HANDLE h = CreateFileA("COM5",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

                 if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                    this->textBox1->Text="Fail";
             }
             }
```

Comment: There's lots of information about `LPCSTR` on Google, particularly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you are using cli, use [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class

Comment: This might be a better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670505/convert-a-systemstring-to-const-char-in-vc  but there are sooooo many to choose from