# conversion from string^ to char * winforms c++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

i m reading path from textbox and then tried to open image

```
String^ P = path->Text;

IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(P);
```

It gives me the following error

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'cvLoadImage' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const char *'
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert it to char *.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a System::String^ to const char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098431/how-do-i-convert-a-systemstring-to-const-char)

Comment: First, you have to know which character set and encoding you want to convert to. You might wish to use the thread's current "code page", which would vary depending on the OS settings, user settings, and API functions called by the thread or inherited from its parent thread. Another choice would be UTF-8. It is used extensively across the Internet, other operating systems and is the default character set/encoding used by many of .NET's file functions. Clearly, since you are passing it to a library function, you need to ensure that the library can take what you pass.

Comment: Second, you have to know the requirements for the lifetime and ownership passing of native string. My guess is that it can be destroyed at the end of the block. If so, you can use a conversion that does this automatically, negating the need for the omitted FreeHGlobal (pointed out by @Hans) in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19474411/2226988) by @user2740528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System::String ^ str = path->Text ;
char* str2 = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str).ToPointer();
printf(str2);
```

Include the following header files

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
```

Comment: Omitting the required Marshal::FreeHGlobal() call is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

**It is Never TOO late.**

here is code I am using

And Do not forget to include the  header file in basic file     #include "saveImg.h" 
call this  by

saveImg () ;

saveImg.h

```
int saveImg (){ // int argc , char* argv[] ) { //  (int argc, char** argv) {
    IplImage* img;
    // if( argc == 2 && (img=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 1))!= 0)     {
    img=cvLoadImage("hello.jpg") ; 
        IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 1 );
        IplImage* net1 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 3 );
        CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        cvCvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        cvSmooth( gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9 ); // smooth it, otherwise a lot of false circles may be detected
        CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles( gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray->height/4, 200, 100 );
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < circles->total; i++ )         {
             float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
             cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
             cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[1]),cvRound(p[2])), cvRound(p[3]), CV_RGB(50,0,100), 3, 8, 0 );
//                     cvWaitKey(0);
        }
        cvNamedWindow( "Original", 1 );
        cvShowImage( "Original", img );
        cvWaitKey(0);

        cvNamedWindow( "circles", 1 );
        cvShowImage( "circles", gray );
        cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Char *  to String ^ in Visual Studio C++ 10   and above

I tested this and OK  while making a small Calculator....

```
// Variables  : 

char * number1 ; 
double num1 ; 
String ^ no1 ; 


     number1 =    (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(no1).ToPointer();  num1 = atof (number1)  ;
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of user2740528's answer?  The only difference is that you interpret the string as a floating point number afterwards, which isn't related to the question.